# How can I serve my GraphQL docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, express, graphql

I'd like to have two different docker containers running:

- ReactJS front-end (created using `create-react-app`)
- NodeJS back-end (GraphQL endpoint)

The first one is easy. I've ran `npm build` and used `nginx` to serve the application. This works fine and I've had no issues.

The second one is being problematic. I can only access it via `localhost:3001` rather than `my_ip_addr:3001` even though I've allowed port 3001 in my firewall configuration. This also only worked for an hour or so - the API is no longer accessible to the front-end and I'm not sure why.

My server file looks like this:

```
import express from 'express';
import { graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress } from 'apollo-server-express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as Schema from './schema';

const cors = require('cors');

const PORT = 3001;
const server = express();

const schemaFunction =
  Schema.schemaFunction ||
  function() {
    return Schema.schema;
  };
let schema;
const rootFunction =
  Schema.rootFunction ||
  function() {
    return schema.rootValue;
  };
const contextFunction =
  Schema.context ||
  function(headers, secrets) {
    return Object.assign(
      {
        headers: headers,
      },
      secrets
    );
  };

server.use(cors());
server.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}), graphqlExpress(async (request) => {
  if (!schema) {
    schema = schemaFunction(process.env)
  }
  const context = await contextFunction(request.headers, process.env);
  const rootValue = await rootFunction(request.headers, process.env);

  return {
    schema: await schema,
    rootValue,
    context,
    tracing: true,
  };
}));

server.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
  endpointURL: '/graphql',
  query: `# Run some stuff
`,
}));

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`GraphQL Server is now running on http://localhost:${PORT}/graphql`);
  console.log(`View GraphiQL at http://localhost:${PORT}/graphiql`);
});
```

How can I have this running inside a docker container, accessible to another docker container? I don't care about it being accessible from outside of my Linux server (in fact, that could be a bonus) but I do need the front-end container to be able to access the API endpoint.

Edit:

Dockerfile (frontend)

```
# build environment
FROM node:9.6.1 as builder
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@1.1.1 -g --silent
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.13.9-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/client/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Dockerfile (gql server)

```
FROM node
RUN mkdir /server
WORKDIR /server
COPY package.json /server
RUN npm install
COPY . /server
CMD ["npm", "run", "server"]
```

The last command runs this: `nodemon server/src/server.js --exec babel-node -e js`

The docker command is: `docker run -dit --restart unless-stopped -p 3001:3001 {image_id}`

Comment: `but I do need the front-end container to be able to access the API endpoint.` Are you sure?

Comment: You may want to read up about docker networking at https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/. Additionally you might want to provide your docker commands/dockerfiles you use to build and start your container. Otherwise it will be hard to help you out. Moreover this question doesn't seem to be related to express, graphql rather than docker ;).

Comment: Can you post you `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @Baboo_ I've attached my docker files and commands

Comment: If I got it right, you'd like that nginx manages both the client and forward the requests to the api. e.g. `http://localhost/` is served directly by nginx while `http://localhost/api/*` will be forwarded to the server. Is it correct?

Comment: So the way I had it when running locally is that the client (http://localhost) would call the graphql endpoint (http://local host:3001/graphql). I’m trying to replicate this now it’s on a server

Comment: if your react app is dependent upon a graphql schema created by a server, then you have to keep the react app from starting until the server has booted up.

Answer (score 0):

use docker compose to make them run in the same network, docker-compose will create a network on its own and your service will run in it.
this might fix the issue

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  my_back:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis-db
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

  my_front:
    image: my-image
    container_name: front-end
    environment:
      REDIS_HOSTNAME: "redis-db"
```

container name = the hostname

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may lay in docker networking. Your frontend container may not be able to reach your backend because both containers aren't in the same network. You can perfectly create 2 containers and a network to connect them both.

However, I'd suggest you look into [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). In short with a compose file you can define multiple services with volumes, networks, ports connected to the host. You can define a network in your docker-compose file and access the other containers in the network by using the service name where you would put an ip or a hostname in your frontend app.

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - backend
    restart: always
  backend:
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
```

Comment: `env_files: .env` is not necessary and it creates misunderstandings. The `.env` file is optional by design. If you want to have a mandatory environment file, you should choose a different name. e.g.  `app.env`.

Comment: docker-compose will create a network on its own so it's not necessary to create a new network. You'd want to create a network if you want a special setup.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may lie in your GraphQL Dockerfile.  Do you also need an EXPOSE in here, e.g.:

```
EXPOSE 3001
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose):

> The EXPOSE instruction informs Docker that the container listens on
> the specified network ports at runtime.

EDIT: Apologies.  According to the docs, the *-p* flag overrides these settings at runtime, so actually unlikely to make much difference.